# Android annotations problems accessing TextView from another class

Tags: android, annotations

I recently started using android annotations and I am trying to set text to various TextViews from within a class (MyService).

Unfortunately the app crashes with a nullpointerexception when I am trying to set the text.

I already looked at the annotations ([documentation](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views)) and **searched on stackoverflow** for identical problems but I am unable to find the correct way in this.

*If someone could help me in doing this the right way, I would be gratefull.*

Please be gentle with downvotes as I am trying to learn annotations.

The class (**DownloadsDialog**) where the TextViews are intiated through (**@ViewById**):

```
@EFragment(R.layout.downloads_dialog)
public class DownloadsDialog extends BaseDialog implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<BaseResponse> {
..
@ViewById(R.id.statusTxt)
    TextView mStatusTxt;

@ViewById(R.id.sizeTxt)
    TextView mSizeTxt;

@ViewById(R.id.progress1)
    ProgressBar mProgress;
..
}
```

And this is the class (**MyService**) from which I am trying to **set text** to these TextViews:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
..
public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }
..

class MyDownloadDownloadStatusListenerV1 implements DownloadStatusListenerV1 {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadComplete(DownloadRequest request) {
            final int id = request.getDownloadId();
            if (id == downloadId1) {
                // How to access TextView in DownloadsDialog?                    
            mStatusTxt.setText("Status: completed");                     

            Log.e("TAG", "download completed");
            }
        }
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Intent service can have view or layout file ?

```
@EFragment(R.layout.downloads_dialog)
```

This way you are telling this is view file in which my all below widgets mentioned so that library will fetch from there and then assign id to your java objects.

```
@EBean
```

But in case of Intent service there is no layout file so it is obvious that it will give null pointer.

Comment: Thx for replying, Ok so the "@ViewById" and "@EBean" should be removed in class MyService? How do I access the TextViews then in DownloadsDialog? Code edited.

Comment: either you can create alert dialog in service and display it using handler or you can make fields static in dialog and pass dialog object to service and then from there you can modify textview object using static reference.

Comment: Ok thx, @ViewById(R.id.statusTxt) public static TextView mStatusTxt; works but Android Studio warns that this causes memory leak.

Comment: Yes it can create leak issue but you have to take care of those things. like screen rotation or termination on low memory etc. accept my answer and upvote as a token of appreciation.